# Put each result of a query in a new page

Tags: vb.net, devexpress, xtrareport

I have a query that give me this results:

```
    Barcode
   ---------
    512364
    012474
    111457
```

And I need to print each result in a new page.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I solve my problem at this way:
>
> It is not necessary to create a
> separate XRBarcode control manually in code for each data row.
> To accomplish this task, bind your report to your SQL query, put the
> XRBarcode control into the report's **Detail band**, and bind the
> **XRBarcode.Text** property to the "**Barcode**" field. After that, set the
> Detail band's **PageBreak** property to the '**AfterBand**' value so each new
> BarCode would start on a new page.

Answer (score 0):

Why don´t you use CHR(12) to to do it?
It´s a hardcode for PAGE-FEED.

Comment: I have already the function to create the barcodes and its works, I only need to knows how can I put each one I a page, thanks

Comment: You must specify in which kind of pages you´re working (Crystal Reports? A bytes file?).  Anyway, if you start the barcode with a CHR(12), when printing the information the printer will jump to a new page. It´s not clear where these pages will be shown: video or print?